# How to capture 360 degree panoramic Image

Tags: java, android, virtual-reality, 360-panorama

Hi i am creating an android app that captures 360 degree panoramic image but to do that the camera launched from app has to be set on that mode.
now my question is how can this be done ? because in every android phone there is different type  of mode like in Samsung(Surround Shot) ,Nexus(Photo Sphere). do i have to create my own app mode? (is there any available SDK or API for this?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to your question? Thanks!

Comment: Its been 2 year. Did you find the answer ?